# Override Database Credentials with Local.xml?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, paypal

I have made multiple attempts to overwrite the Paypal Api Credentials with the local.xml but I can't seem to do it.

I've looked the /Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml ..which seems to highlight the path. Am I doing something wrong? It would be nice to easily swap paypal configurations with different environments.  OR do we have to force the update in the database?

The most obvious attempt:

```
<config>    
<default>
            <paypal>
                <general>
                    <business_account>email@email.com</business_account>
                </general>
                <wpp>
                    <api_password>test</api_password>
                </wpp>
            </paypal>
        </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml files are read first and then overwritten by the values provided from the database - see Mage_Core_Model_Config. So in short what you are trying to do will only work if no values are present in the database, which is hard to guarantee.

Changing the values in the database would be the better approach. Check the `core_config_data` table for the entries you want/need to change. The thing to look out for is if the value is defined in multiple scopes (global, website, store view).